# What is the preferred way of transpiling when some npm dependencies are written in es6 and some aren’t?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

What is the preferred way of transpiling when some npm dependencies are written in es6 and some aren’t? Most examples of babel/webpack say to exclude the `node-modules` folder but that means none of the dependencies will be transpiled, but it does mean that some npm dependencies written in es6 will be transpiled again.

Is there a preferred solution for this?

I am aware of `include`/`exclude` but was hoping for more clarification on the subject but am currently using this:

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(es6-dependency)\/).*/,
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed! The `include` property in the loader object to can accept an array of absolute paths in addition to an array of regexp's. This would allow you to parse the module you know are es6 and still let you exclude node_modules.